# go method - pointer receiver and returning same pointer

Tags: go

A go method on struct receives pointer reference, made some modifications and returning same pointer. The struct has nested reference of same struct: when append method being called with values some reason it was loosing previous values.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type Node struct{
    next *Node
    val int
}
func newNode(val int) (*Node){
    n := Node{
    val: val,
    }
   return &n
}
func (n *Node) append(val int) (*Node){
      for n.next != nil {
     n = n.next
      }
      n.next = newNode(val)
     return n
}

func (n *Node)printList(){
    for n != nil {
         fmt.Printf("%d,", n.val)
         n = n.next
    }
    fmt.Println()
}


func main() {
   n := newNode(3)
   n.printList()
   n = n.append(4)
   n.printList()
   n = n.append(5)
   n.printList()
   n = n.append(6)
   n.printList()    
}
```

```
output:
3,
3,4,
4,5,
5,6,
```

I was expecting 3,4,5,6, - Probably something I totally missing something fundamentals here. appreciate if you have some inputs.

https://play.golang.org/p/-zDH98UNFLa

I was getting expected results when I modify append method not return anything.

Comment: Your code is not very readable. That makes it also hard for you to understand what is happening. 
A big mistake is in your append Method. Because it is not appending anything. I don't understand why you need a for loop, when you append something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function:

```
func (n *Node) append(val int) (*Node){
      for n.next != nil {
     n = n.next
      }
      n.next = newNode(val)
     return n
}
```

*does not* return its original argument in general.  It returns the node that is next-to-last in the (assumed to be non-empty) list.  Hence:

```
n = n.append(4)
```

adds a node holding `4` to the original node holding `3`, then returns the original node holding `3`, but:

```
n = n.append(5)
```

adds a node holding `5` to the original list, but then returns a pointer to the node holding `4`.  That's why you see `4,5,` at this point.  Subsequent calls keep repeating the last two elements for the same reason.

You could modify your `append` function to save the original return value and return *that*:

```
func (n *Node) append(val int) *Node {
    // find current tail
    t := n
    for t.next != nil {
        t = t.next
    }
    t.next = newNode(val)
    return n
}
```

but overall this is still not a great strategy: this `append` does not work when given a `nil`-valued `n`, for instance.  Consider constructing a list type that does handle such cases.  Alternatively, as in [Hsaio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969948/1256452), you can have the caller hang on to the head node directly.  If you do that you could have the `append` function return the tail pointer:

```
func (n *Node) append(val int) *Node {
    n.next = newNode(val)
    return n.next
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
head := newNode(3)
t := append(head, 4)
t = append(t, 5)
t = append(t, 6)
head.printList()
```

(There's already a `List` implementation in the standard Go packages, [`container/list`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/), that does this stuff nicely for you.  Instead of pointing directly to each element in your list, you create an overall list-container instance, which allows you to insert-at-front, insert-at-back, remove-from-anywhere, and so on.  It's a little awkward in that it uses `interface{}` for the data, so it requires a type-assertion to get each node's value.)

Comment: Thank you so much @torek for your time and details. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`append()` returns the pointer of the next node. Therefore `printList()` only print the nodes starting from the next node. If you'd like to print the all nodes in the list, you should add a variable to store the pointer referenced to the starting node of this list.

```golang
func main() {
    n := newNode(3)

    head := n
    head.printList()

    n = n.append(4)
    head.printList()

    n = n.append(5)
    head.printList()

    n = n.append(6)
    head.printList() // 3,4,5,6
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable `n` in `main` function is overrided by `n` in `append` function.